# ¿Como hacer un select de multiples tablas en mysql combinando el registro mas reciente?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, tablas

escribo esta pregunta para consultar lo siguiente. Tengo 4 tablas (historicoCargo, historicoNivel, usuario y persona) las cuales estan relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

[image: relacion]

ahora, lo que he estado intentando obtener es la persona con su usuario (que ya pude realizarlo), pero no puedo obtener el cargo actual ni el nivel actual. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
persona.idPERSONA,
persona.dniPERSONA,
persona.nombresPERSONA,
persona.apellidosPERSONA,
persona.correoPERSONA,
cargo.nombreCARGO,
nivel.nombreNIVEL,
usuario.nombreUSUARIO,
usuario.estadoUSUARIO
FROM historicocargo 
INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.PERSONA_idPERSONA = historicocargo.PERSONA_idPERSONA
INNER JOIN cargo ON cargo.idCARGO = historicocargo.CARGO_idCARGO
INNER JOIN persona ON persona.idPERSONA = historicocargo.PERSONA_idPERSONA
INNER JOIN historiconivel ON historicocargo.PERSONA_idPERSONA = historiconivel.PERSONA_idPERSONA
INNER JOIN nivel ON historiconivel.NIVEL_idNIVEL = nivel.idNIVEL
        WHERE historicocargo.fechahistoricoCARGO IN (SELECT MAX(historicocargo.fechahistoricoCARGO)
                                                            FROM historicocargo 
                                                            GROUP BY historicocargo.PERSONA_idPERSONA) AND
        historiconivel.fechahistoricoNIVEL IN (SELECT MAX(historiconivel.fechahistoricoNIVEL)
                                                            FROM historiconivel 
                                                            GROUP BY historiconivel.PERSONA_idPERSONA);
END
```

y el unico resultado que obtuve es el siguiente :

[image: resultado]

describo el resultado: como veran se repite el registro ( cosa que no deberia suceder ) segundo, las celdas marcadas con 1 son el registro antiguo, y las marcadas con 2 es la actualizacion del registro. Lamentablemente no he podido darle solucion a mi problema.

seria de mucha ayuda si pudieran ayudarme a encontrar solucion de obtener la persona con su usuario y su cargo y nivel actuales. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero lo siguiente; generar un subquery para cambiar la línea:

```
INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.PERSONA_idPERSONA = historicocargo.PERSONA_idPERSONA
```

mi propuesta; lo primero será que en lugar de `usuario` poner un **subquery**:

```
SELECT 
    PRS.*, 
    (SELECT MAX(fechahistoricoCARGO) FROM historicoCARGO WHERE PERSONA_idPERSONA=USR.idPERSONA ) fehistCargo,
    (SELECT MAX(fechahistoricoNIVEL) FROM historicoNIVEL WHERE PERSONA_idPERSONA=USR.idPERSONA) fehistNivel
FROM
    PERSONA PRS
```

entonces el `INNER JOIN` anterior sería

```
INNER JOIN (subquery) usr ON usr.PERSONA_idPERSONA = historicocargo.PERSONA_idPERSONA
```

> **subquery** entiéndase será sustituido por la propuesta previa.

entonces ya el alias `usr` tendrá las fechas de los históricos para *Cargo* y *Nivel* que deseas más reciente, solo mira el alias que le puse a c/u de los datos.